# Insert Multiple Records in dynamics 365 using single POST Request in Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman, microsoft-dynamics, postman-collection-runner

I am new to use postman and web api. I am trying to insert multiple records on single Post request. If i insert single record its working but issue when i try to insert multiple record.

for single entry working fine

[image]

but when tried to insert multiple it's insert one record with blank "serialNumber" after that it showing data already exits.

[image]

How i can post Multiple record either postman or c#.

Comment: As error states, underlying platform i.e. Microsoft Dynamics is not allowing insertion with duplicate keys ,I recon datasetid is the unique key here. There is nothing wrong with Postman or WebApi rather issue is with data since datasetid is duplicate in request. You need to pass unique keys while inserting the records.

Comment: @mbshambharkar thanks for replying I tried insert multiple records with unique serial number but its not inserted. when I tried Multiple Insert first time it's automatic inserted one record with blank serial number after that its showing data already exits.

Comment: Correct because serial number doesn't look like primary key, dataAreaId looks like primary key and you passing same id for multiple objects.

Comment: dataAreaId always be same "sru" its not Primary key, but serial number is unique. I have thousands of data with with same "sru". If I inserted single records it's successfully insert but I need to insert bulk of data on single request.

Comment: After simple google search of 'dataAreaId Microsoft Dynamics' it is clear that dataAreaId is company id , so you might want to revisit the code whether you are updating correct data/service. It is likely that insert is inserting data to multiple tables than targeted one.

Comment: Can you share some code in your Action/controller or code where it is calling dynamics api?